# Evaluating random forest performance in R

Tags: r, random-forest

Hi I have a following proplem:

I want to evaluate random forest performance and i did following step in R

```
library(randomForest)
set.seed(300)
rf <- randomForest(Survived ~ ., data = ciforest)
rf
#and then evaluate random forest performance
library(caret)
ctrl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number = 10, repeats = 10)

Error: could not find function "trainControl"
```

Comment: Use `sessionInfo()` to see which version of `caret` you have installed and add that information please.

Comment: library(caret)
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘lme4’
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘caret’ was built under R version 3.1.3 
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘caret’

Comment: That sounds like you just don't have the dependencies for the `caret` library installed therefore it won't load. That's really the more important message here. No reason to expect to find a function from a package that didn't load.